# Cannot Combine Conditions Normally in If Statement in VBScript

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to determine if it's between the hours of 12 am and 1 am. Here is my if statement:

```
If InStr(Time,"12") AND InStr(Time,"AM") Then 
    ' Do something
Else
    ' Do something else
End If
```

The problem is that this statement evaluates to false, even if both of the conditions are true. I know this because I have tried a nested if like this

```
If InStr(Time,"12") Then
    If InStr(Time,"AM") Then
        ' Do something
...
```

And that works. This also works

```
If InStr(Time,"12")<>0 AND InStr(Time,"AM")<>0 Then
    ' Do something
...
```

But if it works as a nested if, why can't I test both of the nested if conditions in a single if statement?

I replaced the InStr function calls with the values that they return

```
If 1 AND 10 Then
    ' Do something
Else
    ' Do something else
End If
```

And the same thing happened: the if statement evaluated as false and the "Do something else" commands were executed instead. But when I nested the second condition as another if statement inside the first if statement, the "Do something" commands were executed.

Why is that and is there any way to do this without the <>0 and without nesting?

Comment: The `AND` operator in `If x AND y` performs **a bitwise comparison** of identically positioned bits in two numeric expressions. Apply `If x * y` rather as **false**  has a value equal to **0** and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, that's weird but I guess it makes sense. If you put this as an answer I will mark it as the answer

Comment: `Instr` does not return `True` or `False`. It returns the position of the first occurrence of the search string or `0` if it is not found. Maybe that is confusing you?

Comment: aphoria - 0 evaluates to False, and any non-zero number evaluates to True. If True AND True Then will always execute, so it stands to reason that If (any non-zero number) AND (any non-zero number) Then will execute as well, since both statements evaluate to True, but it looks like in VBScript AND is similar to an = sign if it is comparing two numbers instead of booleans. At least that's what I'm getting from what JosefZ is saying

Comment: Right, that's my point, `Instr` does not return a boolean, it returns an integer.

Comment: The problem is that VBScript uses the same operators for boolean *and* bit operations, depending on the data type of the operands. The behavior is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zy95hw.aspx). To enforce a boolean comparison you need to use `InStr(...) > 0` or `CBool(InStr(...))` (both of which evaluate to a boolean result) instead of just `InStr(...)` (which evaluates to a numeric result).

Comment: I ended up using CBool(InStr()) on both conditions. I think that way makes it easiest to understand the intent of the statement. Ansgar Wiechers, you gave the clearest explanation, the most readable solution, and you supported it with documentation, If you restate your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer. Otherwise, I will answer it myself. The one answer that we have thus far is more complex than a way I proposed (and rejected) in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you observed is caused by the fact that VBScript uses the same operators for boolean and bit operations, depending on the data type of the operands. The [`InStr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317897/cannot-combine-conditions-normally-in-if-statement-in-vbscript#comment91585480_52317897) function returns a numeric value unless one of the strings is `Null`, so the operation becomes a bitwise comparison instead of a boolean comparison, as [JosefZ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c) pointed out. The behavior is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zy95hw.aspx):

> The `And` operator also performs a bitwise comparison of identically positioned bits in two numeric expressions and sets the corresponding bit in `result` [...]

Demonstration:

```
>>> WScript.Echo "" & (True And True)
True
>>> WScript.Echo "" & (6 And 1)   '0b0110 && 0b0001 ⇒ 0b0000
0
>>> WScript.Echo "" & (6 And 2)   '0b0110 && 0b0010 ⇒ 0b0010
2
```

To enforce a boolean comparison you need to use `InStr(...) > 0` or `CBool(InStr(...))` (both of which evaluate to a boolean result) instead of just `InStr(...)` (which evaluates to a numeric result).

Comment: FYI I used CBool(InStr(…)) for both conditions and it works perfectly. It was the simplest way suggested and the one that preserved the meaning of the If statement best. Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the explanation of the way VBScript handles these operations. I just discovered fatal flaw in the way I was approaching the actual problem: This condition will test true any time during the AM when the hours, minutes, or seconds equals 12, not just the hours. Instead I'm using `If Hour(Time) = 0 Then`

Answer (score 4):

```
If Time() >= TimeValue("12:00:00") AND Time() <= TimeValue("23:59:59") then 
   'Do Something
ElseIf  Time() >= TimeValue("00:00:00") AND Time() <= TimeValue("01:00:00") then 
   'Do the same 
Else
   'Do something different
End If
```

This should work :)

Comment: What is with the first condition, the OP asked for between 12 AM and 1 AM not 12 PM and 11:59:59 PM?

Comment: I would mark this as the answer if not for two things: 1) while this will work, this is a far more complicated way of doing this. I'd rather use InStr(Time,"12") <> 0 AND InStr(Time,"AM") than that. You've turned 5 lines into 7; 2) as Lankymart points out, the arguments supplied to the TimeValue() function are incorrect. I do appreciate the input, though

Comment: @Lankymart Together with the ElseIf condition it is betwen 12am and 1am.
And that is also why you need two conditions for it, we are looking for times on two different days.

Answer (score 1):

Date and Time are stored as [number of days](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/scripting/working-with/time/vbscript.html), where midnight is 0.0, and 1 am is 1/24 :

```
If Time <= 1/24 Then       ' or If Time <= #1am# Then
```

Answer (score -1):

When you using `Time()` function and if result  like that  `10:12:12 AM` in this way `Instr` will result `Ture`  because `Instr` by default use `vbbinarycompare` looking For any `12`in binary format in  `10:12:12 AM` and there is sec and min 12 so it will Return True .
just try this :

```
  myHour=replace(Time,Right(Time,9),"")     'get only the hour from time
  myAMPM=replace(Time,Time,Right(Time,2))     'get only AM or PM from time
    If InStr(1,myHour,12,1) > 0 AND InStr(1,myAMPM,"AM",1) > 0 Then 
       wscript.echo "True"
    Else
      wscript.echo "False"
    End If
```

Comment: VBscript and vb.net have the same problem you have to feed them everything ready for work but process inside process in process  at this time  error happen